# Visualizing the data in seaborn

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a model and ran it on a random data (ranging from 1000 to 10001 with a step of 1000) to get the loss value after 10 epochs, time taken for computation. I used 3 different optimizers SGD, RMSProp, Adam for comparison. Now I wanted to visualise the time taken for different input sizes along with the loss.

I have the following lists/arrays:
time_sgd, time_rmsprop, time_adam - each of length 10 (1000 to 10001 with step-size 1000)
loss_sgd, loss_rmsprop, loss_adam - each of length 10 (the final loss for each imput size)

I decided to use `seaborn` for a scatterplot with `input_size` on the x-axis, `time` on the y-axis and `loss` as the size of the data points. I tried the following code but it is displaying in separate graphs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.relplot(x=range(10), y=time_sgd, kind="scatter", size=loss_sgd, hue=loss_sgd)
sns.relplot(x=range(10), y=time_rmsprop, kind="scatter", size=loss_rmsprop, hue=loss_rmsprop)
sns.relplot(x=range(10), y=time_adam, kind="scatter", size=loss_adam, hue=loss_adam)
plt.show()
```

I want all the visualization in a single graph like this:

```
plt.scatter(range(10), time_sgd, label='SGD')
plt.scatter(range(10), time_rmsprop, label='RMSProp')
plt.scatter(range(10), time_adam, label='Adam')
plt.xlabel('Input size in 1000')
plt.ylabel('Time in seconds')
plt.title('Time comparison')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But the issue in the last code is that it is not distinguishing the 3 points based on loss. I want the sizes of the data points for the same input size to differ based on the loss value.

Comment: The seaborn relplot is designed to display data on a grid. You seem to want one scatterplot, so you should use [`sns.scatterplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot), which you seem to confuse with the matplotlib function `plt.scatter()`.

Comment: @Mr.T I have intentionally used matplotlib. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: But `hue` is a seaborn feature, not a matplotlib feature. You can implement this functionality in matplotlib easily by translating values into colors but since you use seaborn, why would you want to reinvent the wheel?